# grails domain relationship

Tags: hibernate, grails, pagination, lazy-loading, grails-orm

I have a class called `School` it has many `Students`, so now when I read instance of `School` using `School.read(id)`, I don't want all the students to be fetched eagerly so I changed fetching strategy to `lazy`,

but now it will fetch all the `students` when I will access `school.students`, I want to set manually first 5 `students` then if require 5-10, so on

How can we customize lazy fetching this way ?

`School` has many `Student`

`Student` has no relationship with `School` individually

Answer (score 2):

You can customize how many results are fetching during lazy loading using **batchSize**:

```
class Book {
…
static mapping = {
    batchSize 10
   }
}
```

See the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/batchSize.html).

**Edit**

Instead of calling `School.students` you can create a simple service with your query

```
class SchoolService{

def getLastStudents(School school, int max, int offset){
        // (Not tested but should be something like this)
        def query = "select student from School school join school.students student where school=:school"
        def students = School.executeQuery(query, [school: school], [max: max, offset: offset]) }

}
```

Then call `schoolService.getLastStudents(school, 10, 0)` for example to get the last 10 students.

You can read all about Gorm criteria in the [official documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#querying).

Comment: if we don't specify it, will it load all the students into memory when we access school.students or it will load as we iterate through list ?

Comment: and can I query only to fetch top 10 students for the first time

Comment: Yes it will load all students when you access school.students.  Using a batch size will lower the number of queries done by Hibernate to your DB (1 query will retrieve 10 objects instead of 10 queries for example). So in your case I would suggest you to create a custom query with a limit set to 10 to get your top 10 students.

Comment: ok but where can I specify to invoke the query when I hit school.students

Comment: I made a suggestion in my response on how to implement this.

Comment: Thanks Benoit, could you tell me how to use HQL or critreria here to get top students based on property called `rank`

Comment: Student doesn't have property called school, its one directional